# Jquery tabs - use onclick function to get a content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

After having fetched external content via Ajax, I want to get an internal content.
For that I tried to use `onclick` but it doesn't work. I have an error saying:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load javascript:void(0);. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tab1">tab1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">tab2</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:loadTest();">tab3</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tab1">
     <p>blabla</p>      
</div>  
<div id="tab2">
     <p>blabla</p>      
</div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
function loadTest(){
    return "this content must be displayed tab3";
}
```

How can I get any data from the client to put it into a div corresponding to tab3

Comment: First of all remove `javascript:void(0);' from `href` attr

Comment: Secondly `onclick` handler must return `boolean` (true or false). `loadTest` return `string`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're already using [jQuery UI Tabs](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/), I would suggest you to make use of [**`activate`** events](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate).

```
$(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        activate: function (event, ui) {
            alert(loadTest());
        }
    });
});
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7CHrs/)

Comment: Thanks but with your demo I have a popup alert for all clicked tabs, then I want to have the string inside a <div>.

Comment: @Jils you can. It is easy to customize the good.  in which you need the string?

Comment: on clicking on tab3 the string should be appears inside the corresponding div as "blabla" for tab1 and tab2

Comment: I'm using Chrome and your demo there is also the same error that I have

Comment: @Jils what is use of the `<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:loadTest();">` there is no need to use it. this can be handled via jQUery itself.

Comment: If I remove <code>href="javascript:void(0);</code> the page is reloaded and doesn't stop.

Comment: @Jils ASIK I dont find any reason for this code, `<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:loadTest();">tab3</a></li>
</ul>` instead you can simply do as given in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7CHrs/2/

Comment: I have two questions: its work. I have solution to get the index of the tab how to use it without using hardcoded "tab3"?
When I regresh the page the string is not put until I click to the tab. Is there a possibility to also insert the string to the actived tab without clicking after refreshing?

Comment: @Jils you can get the currently active tab using `$('#tabs').tabs('option', 'active');` Using that you can change your code

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use a onClick? jQuery has a function to handle content that is not yet on the page.

You should use the `.on` function from jQuery.
You can do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#tabs').on('click', 'li', loadtest)
});
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DyRQZ/